# Create an adjacency matrix of three variables with dplyr in R

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, aggregate, tidyverse

I am picking my eyes out to figure this out on Friday night.
My data looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(teamA=c("Italy","Italy","England","England"),
                 teamB=c("Germany","Greece","Germany","Greece"), win=c(0,1,1,1))
df
    teamA   teamB win
1   Italy Germany   0
2   Italy  Greece   1
3 England Germany   1
4 England  Greece   1
```

and I want transform it to a matrix that  look like this. Preferably with dplyr but I am so desperate that does not matter

```
         Italy   England 
Germany  0         1

Greece   1         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `xtabs` from `base R` and set the attributes to NULL (No packages needed)

```
out <- xtabs(win ~ teamB + teamA, df)
names(dimnames(out)) <- NULL
```

Comment: I can't find any simpler solution than `xtabs`, upvoted already :)!

Answer (score 2):

Using `pivot_wider` -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = teamA, values_from = win) %>%
  column_to_rownames('teamB') %>%
  as.matrix

#.       Italy England
#Germany     0       1
#Greece      1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `igraph`

```
graph_from_data_frame(df) %>%
    set_vertex_attr(name = "type", value = names(V(.)) %in% df$teamA) %>%
    as_incidence_matrix(attr = "win")
```

gives

```
        Italy England
Germany     0       1
Greece      1       1
```